# custom devise registrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app. I use the devise gem for the user part and want to customize the registration like this:

1. When the user enters the signup, the form to fill in the email will be displayed
2. After checking valid, a confirmation email will be sent with the registration link
   and display the message sent mail
3. When you click on it, the corresponding registration form for that email will appear

I'm new to rails, hope everyone supports it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could follow this How-To: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Email-only-sign-up

After testing the email-only-signup-howto locally, i recognized some missing route.

If you click on the confirmation link, which controller is processing your request?

Should be `Users::ConfirmationsController` and not `ConfirmationsController`.

The missing route was:

```rb
devise_for :users, controllers: {
  sessions: 'users/sessions', confirmations: 'users/confirmations'
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer

I am following Current approach
but in step 4: Override the Devise definition of password_required? in your model:
I don't really understand which model to overwrite (user.rb?)

Comment: Yes, this should be the user model.

Comment: I have done all the steps but after clicking on the confirmation link it leads to the login page and not the page take the user to a webpage that asks them to set their password.

Comment: after struggling with formatting in comments, i updated my answer ...

Comment: I fixed it today and it worked. there is one more question. If I want to show the edit password and edit user information after the user authenticates, how should I do it? Thanks for the support

Comment: Do you want to show the "edit password" page every time, a user authenticates or just after the confirmation process one time?

Comment: I spent a day researching devise and I thought maybe I found the solution. Thank you so much for your help